# How to make a tilda screen always on back as part of wallpaper

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, startup-applications, tilda

I'm using [tilda](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda) on 17.10 in order to create a terminal as part of my wallpaper. I have most of the graphics down (a fitting color scheme, transparent background etc. ). However one thing I can't get working is for tilda to be always on the back, right now tilda is transparent so I can see when a screen goes behind it, however when I click on such a screen I instead tend to end up clicking on the tilda screen instead.

I already know that

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,below
```

causes a terminal screen to go behind everything else, however I can't figure out how to make tilda do that on startup without also closing the tilda screen inimitably.

Comment: Make sure "always on top" is unchecked under General settings.

Comment: @Seth ah that at least makes it not "always on top" but I'm trying to get it to be "always on bottom"

Answer (score 0):

I have a small bash script for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

#open tilda
tilda &
#wait a second to make sure tilda is open
sleep 1

wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,below
```

copy the code above to a file for example my_tilda

make it excutable

```
sudo chmod 755 my_tilda
```

test if it works

```
./my_tilda
```

if it works you can move it to /usr/local/bin

```
mv my_tilda /usr/local/bin/tilda_bg
```

now you can use start it by:`tilda_bg`

hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same question right now, and it seems as if you have to not only disable 'Always on top', **but also check 'Set as Desktop window'.**

At least that seems to have done it for me.

```bsh
$ tilda --version
Tilda 1.4.1
```